# Filter a list of layers under drop down

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

Is there a way to filter a list of layers under the drop down whenever selecting a layer to run a geoprocessing tool? Because I have 40 some layers displayed in the Table of Contents of ArcMap which can be pretty messy.

Comment: Drag the layer from the table of contents and drop into your layer dropdown on your tool dialog.

Comment: Another tip is to start typing the layer's name after clicking the down arrow element to open the list of the layers. This will move selection as you type so you can choose the needed layer.

Comment: Third tip, drag the layers you want to process into a new data frame and run the geoprocessing tool from there.